Populating Null in an INT column of MySQL Table
I have data as follows in my csv:

ID, NAME, fav_digit
1   abc      2
2   xyz
3  pqr      7

Now, I have created the table in the MySQL table using the data types Int, Varchar(7), Int  respectively.
But the table has populated 0  in the row where id = 2 This means that the fav_diigit is unintentionally representing 0, but in reality, the data is not present. Is it that we can't populate NULL  in an INT column?
I need to indicate that the cell is empty rather than a digit like 0
I was expecting NULL  value in second row.BTW, I have connected my file from excel to MySQL using this command/query:
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\path\to\file\file.csv'
INTO TABLE file_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, Name, fav_digit);


Of course you CAN store NULL in an int column.  Whether LOAD DATA does that or not is the question.  Did you set DEFAULT NULL for that column?

I did set the DEFAULT NULL but seems the issue persists.I feel it is stemming from Infile.. command.
